# Regex to match given string filenames in a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a string

> PrintFileURL("13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-29.zip","13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-29.zip",0,"184277","Jun 29  1:30","/icons/default.gif")

Also

> PrintFileURL("13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip","13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip",0,"53147","Jun
>   29  3:33","/icons/default.gif")

What could be the Regex If I want to extract both  `13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip` and `13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-29.zip` from the above strings using c#...?

Comment: `^(.+)$`...? What exactly do you consider the filename? The entire string looks like the file name to me.

Comment: can't you specify simply the file name to match as everyone will confuse on which is the filename from this..? @akhil

Comment: @akhil: Please provide an example of a valid extraction from any or both of your strings.

Comment: The regex should extract `13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip`  and `13572_BranchInformationReport_2012-06-29.zip` Both from the above strings

Comment: Actually these strings are part of a file that contaings 100s of such strings all containing different file names but in the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one should work exactly for first two files, but won't work if there any additional special characters in file names:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string example = "PrintFileURL(\"13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip\",\"13572_IndividualInformationReportDelta_2012-06-29_033352.zip\",0,\"53147\",\"Jun 29 3:33\",\"/icons/default.gif\")";
            Console.WriteLine(example);

            const string pattern = "\\\"([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_]*?\\..*?)\\\"";
            var regex = new Regex(pattern);
            var result = regex.Matches(example);
            foreach (Match item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Groups[1]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

[Regex](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?31bc5)

and then

```
var regex = new Regex("@(?<=\")(.*?)(?=\")");

var result = regex.Matches(example);
foreach (Match item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Groups[1]);
}
```